# REST API - Filter Available Fields Choice Results?

Tags: 2013, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem, api

We have a very large choice (nearly 20,000 options!!!) field that we want to be able to retrieve the choices, and preferably filter them on the server side.

This is the call to get the options

```
_api/web/availablefields?$filter=EntityPropertyName%20eq%20%27InternalName%27&$select=Choices
```

Is there an extra bit of syntax we can use to filter them on the server side? Or is there no choice but to do it client side?

Cheers